# Linux shell equivalent to "cmd /k"

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, shell

I am working in a multi-platform (Windows and Linux), multi-shell environment. The Windows "shell", `cmd`, can be executed as `cmd /k command`, which makes it execute `command`, but then its console remains open and accepts interactive input from the user.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect with Unix shells? I'd need it for `sh`, `[t]csh` and `bash`, or at least for some of them.

I've tried experimenting with `bash` options `-c` and `-i` or their combination, but have had no success so far. The shell always terminates when it's done executing `command`.

The `command` I'd need to run is `source somefile`, but I still want the shell to source its normal startup (`*rc`) files as well.

Some more context: the shell will actually be executed from a Python script. Its purpose is to set up some environment and then present an interactive shell to the user.

Comment: Try "-s".  Also, you might need to do "--init-file somefile" in order to get somefile to be able to set environment variables for your shell.  If you also need the user's .rc files then "source ~/.bashrc" from somefile.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Thanks for the tip. I was also considering this (and it's my backup plan, actually), but to me, this seems like duplicating the knowledge of how `bash` does its startup in my script. I know `bash` is unlikely to change in this regard, but it still feels like introducing a maintenance coupling. And I couldn't find an equivalent for `sh` or `csh`.

Comment: agree.  I just tried "cat foo - | bash".  (Where foo is a file containing "echo hi").  (This creates a stream with the contents of foo, followed by stdin.)  It doesn't really give what you want (among other things, the prompt is not set, and I think you might not be attached to a terminal.)  But it does allow execution of a command followed by allowing commands from stdin.